# Docker-compose: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ssl'

Tags: docker-compose

Today I have tried use docker-compose and got next error:

```
>>docker-compose 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('docker-compose==1.7.1', 'console_scripts', 'docker-compose')()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
return self.resolve()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 14, in <module>
from . import errors
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/errors.py", line 9, in <module>
from docker.errors import APIError
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
from .client import Client, AutoVersionClient, from_env # flake8: noqa
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 22, in <module>
import websocket
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/websocket/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from ._core import *
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 39, in <module>
from ._socket import *
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/websocket/_socket.py", line 28, in <module>
from ._ssl_compat import *
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ssl'
```

OS: OpenSuse Leap 42.1 
Docker-compose: 1.7.1
Docker: 1.11.2
libopenssl-devel installed

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://paltman.com/getting-ssl-support-in-python-251/) will help?

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade OpennSSL to version 1.0.1i-15.1 from 1.0.1i-2.36.1 has fixed my problem.